# Is ET watching "I Love Lucy" right now?

Tags: physics, aliens

Is it realistic to suppose an alien civilisation 60 light-years away could now be receiving tv transmissions of "I Love Lucy"?

[This](http://www.space.com/2533-listening-ets-television.html) site says emphatically not, but my brother say ET could easily do it if he wanted to. Please settle the argument, somebody!

ADDED 11th July: Just to clarify, my brother is prepared to assume ET's detection facilities could be *incredibly* good (i.e. - receiver array as wide as a planet or larger, focussed exactly on the earth), and almost infinite processing power to separate signal from noise.

In short, the question comes down to whether there's some upper limit on how close ET would need to be, before 'background noise' would overwhelm any feasible attempt at detection. I don't know enough about information theory to even know whether such a limit can be proven to exist, let alone whether it can be calculated to an actual value.

Comment: It's very unlikely that a undirected signal is still correctly receivable after 55 light years. It's original power would be spread over a sphere with a radius of 55 light years. You can easily imagine that its long gone below the background noise.

Comment: How strong is the background noise? Is it equally strong everywhere?

Comment: @user unknown: I don't think it's a matter of just comparing signal strength to noise. More processing power could identify an information-modulated signal even against higher background noise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No. In the absence of any error correction, even the tiniest bit of noise will cause some corruption of the signal. If Forward Error Correction is used, the amount of FEC determines the maximum tolerable noise. (See also [Shannon–Hartley theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon–Hartley_theorem))

Comment: @MSalters: I don't like to be lazy, but I doubt my maths is up to ferretting out the truth on this one, even with your link. Is it mathematically possible to establish a maximum distance beyond which no feasible detection equipment (coupled to effectively infinite processing power) could abstract usable information from those early high-powered broadcasts? I mean purely on the basis how 'background noise' comes to dominate the issue.

Comment: @ **Whoever voted to close this Question**. Can you explain why you think my question is 'off topic'? My brother is/was sceptical that we could be *certain* ET would not be able to receive/decode those transmissions from any particular distance. I feel there should be a definitive answer based on maths/information theory, but I don't know enough to prove this. A knowledgable respondent could presumably either confirm my suspicions, or show conclusively that no such 'outer limit' could be defined.

Comment: Maybe "Lucy" hasn't actually been noticed, but I wonder about the nuclear tests, like the 50-megaton "Tsar Bomba" set off by the USSR in 1961. As Arthur C. Clarke observed, they may be headed here as fast as their paddywagon can go.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey: Possibly. I don't know enough physics to say whether the emf footprint of a nuclear bomb is easily distinguished from natural phenomena, and if so at what distance. Much as I respect Clarke's fiction, I wouldn't trust his scientific authority on that issue any more than his denial of charges of paedophilia. In both matters I keep an open mind, but lean towards disbelief.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: processing power really isn't the problem if you know what you're targetting. The SETI project needs so many PCs because they're listening essentially to all stars. The real restriction is the receiver size, because that seperates the signal from earth from the noise from elsewhere. And that receiver size goes up _very_ quickly.

Comment: @MSalters: Surely 'at the margin', so to speak, the information content of the signal is only just discernable above the increasing 'noise', so maximum processing power is needed to get right to the upper limit. *Even* if ET somehow knew exactly what *kind* of 'artificial' modulation he was looking for. But I still want to know if there's a theoretical upper limit calculatable from information theory, quantum mechanics, or other 'first principles'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The remove noise, you essentially apply error correction. You only need a lot of processing power if the signal has been designed with a complex Error Correction mechanism. Analog TV isn't; that was designed for the simple analog TV's of the fifties.

Comment: To take it too literally...  No.  As seen in Star Wars 1, and later explained as part of Star Wars Canon, E.T.'s people are from the "far far away" Star Wars galaxy, came out here for a visit, and have gone home.  Our radio transmissions (no matter what the strength) are nowhere near that (or any other) galaxy yet.  So, no, thanks to them having FTL drives, they flew through the transmission on the way home and are not receiving it at this time!  :-)

Comment: @Brian Knoblauch: When I talk about ET I assume we're still in the 'real world', so to speak. If we allow that ET might have FTL technology, we might as well assume he does time travel too (so he could be reading this sentence *before* I've typed it). Since our nearest galaxy neighbour is 25-42K light-years away, I feel we can safely forget about extragalactic ET for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your brother is right.  The answers here all are for Earth-class facilities, which indeed are inadequate for the task.  But planet-sized, or even smaller antennas, can do the trick out to anywhere our signals have gotten so far.

I've written up (with some reasonably detailed computations) what would be possible with alien-class facilities, and they *could* watch our TV if they wish to.  See

http://contactincontext.org/lucy.pdf

Comment: I'm sold on this! The "factor of a million" in the current top answer is in fact small beer in the context we're talking about. I think our "useable within a single box" computer processing power has gone up by significantly more than that in the last 50 years, which is a mere blink of an eye (who's to say ET didn't start evolving towards intelligence / technology millennia or even *millions* of years before us?). But the main reason I switched my "accept" is your point about exploiting the redundancy of hundreds/thousands of repeats (which obviously would apply in spades to *"I Love Lucy"* :)

Comment: This answer does not seem to have a valid source...

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up? Also, you should include all the relevant information in your answer, not in a link.

Answer (score 21):

**Note:** *Since the link in the question actually gives a good answer I'll use it.*

From [Seth Shostak](http://www.seti.org/shostak) (**SETI** Institute), via [Space.com](http://www.space.com/2533-listening-ets-television.html):

> **The first episode of "I Love Lucy" was
>   broadcast sometime on October 15,
>   1951.**
>
> [The signal] is still going. Every day, that
>   first installment passes through an
>   additional 4 thousand trillion
>   trillion trillion cubic kilometers of
>   the cosmos.
>
> Given that stars in our galactic
>   neighborhood are separated by about 4
>   light-years, it's easy to figure that
>   **roughly 10 thousand star systems have
>   been exposed to "I Love Lucy" in the
>   past five decades**.
>
> That may suggest a
>   high Nielson rating, but **the chance
>   that extraterrestrials are now hooked
>   on 1950s television is low.**

[...]

> **Imagine that there are alien couch
>   potatoes 55 light-years away** who,
>   bored with their own Fall lineup, have
>   constructed a [**LOFAR**](http://www.lofar.org/)-style antenna (*a telescope consisting
>   of 25 thousand tent-shaped antennas
>   spread across Holland and Germany*) in
>   hopes of picking up "I Love Lucy's"
>   debut.
>
> OK, **how strong is that signal by the
>   time it reaches our putative alien
>   audience at 55 light-years distance?**
>
> Not very. The megawatt broadcast
>   washes over ET's world with a power
>   density of about
>
> - **0.3 million million
>     million million millionths of a watt
>     per square meter**,
>
> which is not exactly
>   a scorching signal.
>
> Could their LOFAR-style antenna find
>   that carrier, thereby indicating that
>   a program was on the air?
>
> Well,
>   engineers have computed that at the
>   frequency of VHF television, LOFAR
>   will have an effective collecting area
>   similar to that of the 305-meter
>   diameter Arecibo antenna in Puerto
>   Rico.
>
> That's big. That's brawny. But not
>   brawny enough. In our SETI experiments
>   at [Arecibo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_Observatory), we could find a signal if
>   it were about *0.1 million million
>   million millionths of a watt per
>   square meter*.
>
> That number, you will
>   notice if you count up the words, is a
>   million times bigger than the "I Love
>   Lucy" carrier at 55 light-years. **The
>   aliens' LOFAR would be inadequate to
>   detect the broadcast by a factor of a
>   million**, a not entirely negligible
>   amount.
>
> **Simply stated: LOFAR couldn't
>   hear it.**
>
> LOFAR would only be able to find TV
>   signals comparable to ours from a
>   **distance of much less than one
>   light-year!**

From [Radio Leakage: Is anybody listening?](http://www.computing.edu.au/~bvk/astronomy/HET608/essay/):

> Hypothetically, **assume that the
>   [Arecibo telescope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_Observatory) was put on the back
>   of a starship making its way into deep
>   space.**
>
> If it was possible to point the
>   telescope back towards Earth, **how far
>   could the starship travel and still be
>   able to detect terrestrial
>   electromagnetic radiation** leaking into
>   space?
>
> Neglecting atmospheric effects:
>
> - An AM radio broadcast could only be
>     detected out to 0.0074 [Astronomical
>     Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit) (AU).
> - FM Radio could be
>     detected out to 5.4 AU.
> - **A 5 Megawatt
>     UHF television picture could be
>     detected out to 2.5 AU**, although the
>     carrier wave could be detected much
>     further; out to 0.3 light years.
>
> (*[1 light year ~ 63,000 AU](http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/conversions/length/light-years-to-astronomical-units.php)* )

The [SETI FAQ](http://setifaq.org/faq.html#1.2.3) says:

> Detection of broadband signals from
>   Earth such as AM radio,
>              FM radio, and television picture and sound would be
>              extremely difficult even at a fraction of a light-year
>              distant from the Sun.
>
> For example, **a TV picture having 5
>              MHz of bandwidth and 5 MWatts of power could not be detected
>              beyond the solar system even with a radio telescope with 100
>              times the sensitivity of the 305 meter diameter Arecibo
>              telescope.**

From [PopSci](http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2010-01/scientists-warn-invisible-earth-hostile-ets-cambridge-alien-conference):

> **Frank Drake, the father of SETI,
>   worried that the switch from analog
>   television and radio signals to
>   digital cable and satellite radio
>   would render Earth invisible to aliens**
>   looking for other life.
>
> ... as more and more people
>   receive their media beamed down to
>   them from digital satellites, not up
>   to them from analog radio towers, that
>   signal slowly fades away, drastically
>   reducing the chance that aliens might
>   detect our tiny blue rock.

**More:**

- [Guardian - Aliens can't hear us](http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2010/jan/27/aliens-cant-hear-us-astronomer)
- [BBC - Can our TV signals be picked up on other planets?](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/7544915.stm)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was undecided/sceptical myself, but I'm pretty well convinced now. More importantly - so is my brother, and if he hadn't tried to big up ET's ability to eavesdrop I wouldn't have given it much credeence at all. Now I'm happy to think the chances of ET hearing us in the near future are vanishingly slim. Plus if ET *did* find us and respond in kind, it would be a *long* time before we could pick up any signal he might send to us!

Answer (score 3):

Obviously all calculations based on inverse square law (i.e. strength of a signal is inversely proportional to the square of distance) is proof enough. But I'd like to remind you of few more factors:

- TV signal back then was VHF, and Earth's troposphere and ionosphere will reflect VHF waves at acute angles back to the surface. See: http://www.df5ai.net/Material/articles3.html
- Given that, only signal which goes practically straight up has chance to leave the Earth's atmosphere;
- [Characteristics of dipole antenna](http://www.wirelesscommunication.nl/reference/chaptr03/antgain.htm) (which happen to be the kind of antennas that were used for TV broadcast at the time), practically prevents any signal to travel straight upwards.

Another argument, would be that the Earth is in a constant movement. It's spinning around it's axis at 360°/24h, which means that Earth spins 7° during one episode of *"I Love Lucy"*. Also Earth travels around the Sun at angle velocity of 360°/365¼d. Note, that few degrees off might not seem much, but at a distance of 55 light years 1° off translates into 1 light year off.

Comment: Hi @var. I agree on all counts except the last point, really. We might rotate, but the waves are emitted uniformly in all directions (more or less), and therefore the only effect the receivers would see is a doppler effect. The rotation argument would apply if the waves were unidirectional, like a laser, but in that case the inverse square law would not apply as long as the waves are coherent (and therefore do not disperse over a larger area as radius increases).

Comment: +1 for the useful observation about earth's spin. But I'm not sure about the '1° translates to a light year. Surely the drop in signal strength between 90° and 89° would not be so great as to matter to ET? The difference in the amount of earth's atmosphere that a signal would have to 'punch through' at 89°would be a tiny fraction of a percent less than at 90°, no?

Comment: @Ski: between unidirectional and omnidirectional there is whole range of possibilities. Even if Earth would have no atmosphere, antenna relatively close to the surface (comparing to Earths curvature), would at most give you 180&deg;  Effects of atmosphere limit that further. If Earth happens to be rotated India/Middle East side towards you, the signal from USA will be completely blocked by Earth itself.

Comment: @var: true, but an omnidirectional signal in close proximity to earth surface would still be visible ~12h/day to someone at 55ly, no? In other words, depending on the direction and the latitude, we "see" any particular star for ~12h/day (and all year long)--so it stands to reason that someone in that star's direction would "see" us for just as long.

Answer (score -1):

Transmission of uncollimated TV and radio background signals seems to die out after 1 lightyear
source:http://www.davidbrin.com/SKEPTICcontactperils.pdf
first page, second paragrph

Comment: Please make this answer more than a link.

Comment: The bit about 1 lightyear is only mentioned in passing, with no figures or substantive argument to back it up, so I can't really go for this answer, sorry. It's an interesting link though, thanks.